# How to reserve the state of an HA verticle between restarts

Tags: vert.x

I'm experimenting with HA verticles and I'm wondering about the best way to preserve state of an HA verticle between restarts. For example, imagine a verticle that represents a web session with various fields that can be modified by user's activity. If that verticle runs on a node that for some reason crashes it will be restarted on another node but the fields will not be restored with the last known value they had before the crash.

I looked at the docs but could not find any "ready to use" API to do the job. Maybe I missed something.

I ended up with the idea to implement states (ie sessions) as `JsonObject`s stored in an `AsyncMap` with the key being the address of the verticle on the event bus (actually the address of the message handler). The address remains the same between restarts because it is provided in the `DeploymentOptions` and thus it is available in the object returned by `config()`, so the re-born verticle "knows" where to look for the session, if any.

I'm not sure whether its the right way to implement this and if there isn't any pitfall I should be aware of.

Thanks for your ideas and feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options here:

1. Use the [SharedData API](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/groovy/#_using_the_shareddata_api) to persist the data between verticles in a cluser-wide storage. The data is kept alive when at least 1 node of the cluster still running.
2. Use the database to persist the data between the restart of the whole clusters. You can pick any DB available.